# NetSuite Search field A equal to field B

Tags: search, netsuite

In a NetSuite search I need to perform two searches.
One for results where field A is equal to field B and a second one where field A does not equal field B.

When I am entering criteria for a search when I select a field and choose `equal to` I am only given the option of entering a set number into the `VALUE` field.

I even looked at highlighting the values which are not equal, though that is the same entry form as the criteria one.

How can I achieve the above results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a formula field using the advanced search dialog. I generally do that like this:

```
case when {firstfield} = {secondfield} then 1 else 0 end
```

and make the formulanumeric test equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to pull this off with {firstField}-{secondField} = 0 and also  != 0 for my other case. Since these are numeric fields to begin with.